# Opening a new terminal window in C

Tags: c, linux, terminal

If I have a C program that I compile successfully and generate an executable, how do I instruct the program to open a new terminal window when I run it from the command line in a pre-existing terminal command prompt? I assume I use the `system()` function but what header is that in and what is the actual command arg it takes?

Comment: The terminal you want probably has a command line option to tell it what executable to run. So you could create a small shell script to call terminal with your program as a command line option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The header file is `stdlib.h` and the function signature is `int system(const char *command)`. So in your case you could call the function like this to spawn a new terminal window:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int exit_status = system("gnome-terminal");
}
```

In C it's common to check the return value of most function calls to determine if something went wrong or to get some more information about the call. The `system()` call returns the exit status of the command run, and is here stored in `exit_status` for further inspection.

See `man system` for the details.

Comment: I just tried that and it works perfectly! T'anks. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which terminal you want to open. There are several: xterm, konsole, gnome-terminal, and a whole bunch of others. For konsole, you would use:

```
system("konsole");
```

The terminal applications are usually in the default PATH, so you don't need to specify an absolute path.

As to which header provides `system()`, all you need to do is read the manual page for it. You do that with the command:

```
man system
```

It provides a whole lot of documentation about `system()`. Pay attention to the reasons why not to use `system()` and whether they're important to you.

Comment: I'm looking to open a gnome-terminal.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute the terminal emulator. In my case (I have Kubuntu) it's Konsole, so it would be `system("konsole")`.

If I wanted it to execute ls on the current working directory, it'd be:

```
system("konsole --hold -e ls .");
```

What you can't do with system is control the spawned terminal.
On the other side, if you use fork+exec, maybe you can interact with it by redirecting its streams (dup2)