# How to open a Linux terminal in a c program ? Is it possibile?

Tags: c, linux, input, terminal, output

I want to open a terminal with an instruction in the code.

For example, I want to manage input and output in two different terminal. One for typing instruction and one for the output of this instructions. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Opening a new terminal window in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19472398/opening-a-new-terminal-window-in-c)

Comment: You don't need C for that. The PIPEs and file descriptors what you need.

Comment: Sorry , i want to open a NEW terminal different from the one i have used for launching the program. something like system("gnome-terminal") is possibile? and if yes , how to redirect the output to this new terminal?

Comment: Update 2 : I notice that open a new terminal from c program is simply, but how to use this ? I want to redirect the ouput  of my program to this new terminal how to do this ?

Comment: Since you mentioned gnome-terminal, do you want the output of your program to appear in a window? Do you even need a full-blown terminal?

Comment: It appears you are describing 1) beginning a new process, 2) passing to it a command, 3) retrieving a response, and 4) closing the process.  So, What have you tried so far?  Can you post your attempt in code?  BTW, a routine built around `FILE *pipe = popen(command, "rt")` would accomplish all of this, with the exception of a visible terminal popping up.